# Distinguishing feature class from shapefiles using ArcObjects?

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, c#, feature-class

```
private IFeatureClass GetFeatureClassSelection() {
        var gxObject = BrowseForFeatureClass(0);
        if (gxObject == null)
            return null;
        var gxDataset = gxObject as IGxDataset;
        IFeatureClass featureClass = null;
        if (gxDataset != null) {
            if (gxDataset.Dataset == null) {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to access selected feature class", "File Selection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                return null;
            }
            _selectedFeatureInformation.WorkspaceType = gxDataset.Dataset.Workspace.Type.ToString();
            featureClass = gxDataset.Dataset as IFeatureClass;
        }
        if (featureClass == null) {
            MessageBox.Show("Feature Classes and Shapefiles are allowed only", "File Selection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            TxtBxSrcFtrClass.Text = string.Empty;
            return null;
        } 
        _selectedFeatureInformation.FtrClass = featureClass;
        TxtBxSrcFtrClass.Text = gxDataset.Dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)_selectedFeatureInformation.FtrClass).Name;
        return featureClass;
    }
```

How can I tell if it is a shapefile or feature class from the returned object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the WorkspaceFactory from the IFeatureClass object and check its [type](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriGeodatabase/esriWorkspaceType.htm).

```
IFeatureClass fClass = ...;
esriWorkspaceType fcType = (fClass as IDataset).Workspace.WorkspaceFactory.WorkspaceType;
```

You could also use WorkspaceFactory.WorkspaceDescription to get a more granular breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the workspace type that the dataset utilizes using the code below. From an IDataset, use the [Workspace](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDataset_Workspace.htm) property when calling the function

```
dim category as String = GetCategory(gxDataset.Dataset.Workspace)

Public Function GetCategory(ByVal pWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace) As String

    Dim sClassID As String
    sClassID = pWorkspace.WorkspaceFactory.GetClassID.Value

    Select Case sClassID
        Case "{DD48C96A-D92A-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15}" ' pGDB
            GetCategory = "Personal Geodatabase"

        Case "{71FE75F0-EA0C-4406-873E-B7D53748AE7E}" ' fGDB
            GetCategory = "File Geodatabase"          '

        Case "{D9B4FA40-D6D9-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15}" ' GDB
            GetCategory = "SDE Database"

        Case "{A06ADB96-D95C-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15}" ' Shape
            GetCategory = "Shapefile Workspace"

        Case "{34DAE34F-DBE2-409C-8F85-DDBB46138011}" ' SDC
            GetCategory = "SDC Workspace"

        Case "{1D887452-D9F2-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15}" ' Coverage
            GetCategory = "ArcInfo Coverage Workspace"

        Case "{7F2BC55C-B902-43D0-A566-AA47EA9FDA2C}" ' InMemory
            GetCategory = "InMemory Workspace"

        Case "{59158055-3171-11D2-AA94-00C04FA37849}" 'OLEDB Workspace
            GetCategory = "OLEDB Workspace"

        Case "{30F6F271-852B-4EE8-BD2D-099F51D6B238}" 'Excel Workspace
            GetCategory = "Excel Workspace"

        Case Else
            GetCategory = "Unknown Workspace Category"
    End Select
End Function
```